# Android Time Zone difference with GMT+1 and GMT-1

Tags: android, datetime, time, gmt

I have google it, but dont find what is the problem in this code.

```
private Date ConvertToDate(String dateString){

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

    Date convertedDate;
    try {
        convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return convertedDate;

}
```

If GMT is -1, then return the correct hour, example hour=23 , but if GMT+1, then returns hour=0 when should be hour=1.
Don't understand why.....any help on this ? 
Thanks